# How can I simulate TC4420 or TC4429 on proteus 8

Tags: switches, mosfet-driver, induction

[image: Project schematics]

I have to use TC4429 MOSFET driver for my project. However I couldn't simulate it on Proteus. Here are the errors it shows:

[image: Netlist linker errors]

How can I fix these? I couldn't find libraries and models for this TC4429CPA device. Where can I find library and model files? Alternatively what device can I use instead?

Comment: I think the first thing to do would be format and punctuate your question, it would make it look professional

Answer (score 1):

The most important part of a MOSFET driver simulation is what you don't have on the schematic: the 5 nanoHenries in each of GND, VDD, and VOUT. Also, you need to include 1,000pF (onchip well_substrate depletion capacitance) per AMP of output drive strength.

With the pin inductances and the onchip capacitance, you have captured the potentially destructive sag in onchip VDD and the rebound of that onchip VDD some few nanoseconds later.

Inductances can range from 5nH (5mm bondwire/leadframe/PCBtrace/PCBvias) to 20nH for DIP use in sockets.

Additionally, the input circuits of power-drivers will vary according to which semiconductor design house and which foundaries are used. The input hysteresis is suspect. The ability to reject VDD collapse (a cause of PowerDriver oscillation) is suspect. The propagation delay will vary 5:1 based on input slewrate and the total input voltage swing. The propagation delay will vary another 5:1 based on VDD and Cload and temperatures and pin inductance.

Just some thoughts.

---

Guidelines for safe operation of Power Drivers

These Power Drivers use large internal MOSFETS as the output transistors; these MOSFETS have **large** gate area and require **large** amounts of charge to turn on and to turn off; the circuitry uses onchip amplifiers and chains of inverters to provide this charge; under fast switching operation (low nanoseconds), the charge primarily comes from the onchip well_substrate junction capacitance; the inductances prevent much charge arriving from offchip, during the first few nanoseconds of output-fet gate-charging; this demand for charge causes RAIL COLLAPSE which impairs the switching time; after the rail collapse, the onchip rails **ring** outward, possibly well beyond the DC breakdown rating;

```
   **To be safe, always have some load capacity attached, 
   so the Rout+Cload serves to dampen the ringing.**
```

I've seen ringing frequency as low as 10MHz (100 nanosecond period) for Power Drivers of size 6 amps and larger. I've seen ringing frequency as high as 100MHz for Power Drivers of size 1Amp and smaller. The package inductance, any sockets, the PCB inductance (vias, traces, planes), and bypass cap inductance, all matter. Also the VDD, affecting the onchip well_substrate charge storage capacitance, matters.